# Request next available item from sharepoint list with jquery

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I have a sharepoint list with two columns, one with one time codes and the other one is yes/no

Like this:

| CODE | USED |
| --- | --- |
| NGTHX–EVLRZ–GHTXD | Yes |
| RYKXB–EOMWD–FZUWL | No |
| DKTUN–YSCWP–PHKWM | No |

So what I'm trying to achieve is with javascript/jquery have a page where you could click a button and receive the next available code in the list and mark that code's used column to Yes.
So next time you click the button you get the next code which aren't marked as used.
This is for a internal service and a user can request a code themselves instead of contacting an administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this rest api endpoint:

```
/_api/lists/getbytitle('list title')/items?$select=CODE&$filter=USED eq 'NO'&$orderby=ID&$top=1
```

It will only return the unused code with the smallest ID.

Comment: Thanks, and to update the Used value to Yes after getting the Code what's the best approach?

Comment: You could use rest api to update the list item too.The official document on rest updating list item:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#update-list-item  Demo:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-a-sharepoint-list-using-rest-api/

Comment: Thanks will look into the rest api more carefully.

Comment: If my answer helps you, you could mark it as the answer and vote for it. Thank you :).